# Is there anyway to scan a document directly from scanner using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, signalr

I created a project that depends on signal-R to send and receive text messages, print files using other side printer and start a video chat using webRTC, All done with jQuery and signal-R.

The only thing remaining is to send a scanned document to the chat directly from scanner, so is there any way to scan a document and append it as image in web page? I've seen a lot of paid methods depends on SDK, but i need to make it by myself.

Comment: `is there any way to scan a document and append it as image in web page`? → `I've seen a lot of paid methods`. You answered your own question.

Comment: Have you checked out this https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/imaging/scan-documents-from-twain-devices-in-jquery/ ?

Comment: @MauriceNino i need a FREE way.

Comment: @JogiMehul licence is too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract is a free OCR program that you could use on the server-side.

```
Get image => transmit image to server => send image to tesseract => do OCR => get text => return text from server
```